# ASP.NET Core Web API returning classes resulting in memory leak?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, garbage-collection, asp.net-core-webapi

Upon request, an ASP.NET Core Web API was created, in such a way that it translates to json or XML output.

A typical return method in it has a syntax like

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("SomeCommand/{id?}")]
public ActionResult<Response.Command> SomeCommand(int id)
{ 
     // ...
     // Some minimal logic nothing that can cause memory strains

     // A class Response containing sub classes as placeholders for values 
     // Each nested class within has a constructor to set its values
     return new Response.SomeCommand(x)  
}
```

ASP.NET does correctly convert the class to a JSON output or XML output no problems there.

However, it slowly uses more and more memory it seems.

Is there a better way to do this?

Or a way to force the garbage collector to free up those classes?

Or shouldn't I worry about it, it's normal GC takes (a long?) time.
(as now it looks like a memory leak).

Comment: It's very difficult to make judgement on your code, But MC provides a duc about [Debug a memory leak in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak), You can refer to this doc.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?
I seem to encounter this as well

Comment: I was using some libs back then to generate reports i trusted those to work (devexpress) it turned out that our json was to deeply nested for them raised a case and they got us a special fix. But i'm working for antoher company so dont now, but you might check libs you use. if its not MS be extra sure that it isnt causing it, newtonsoft can be problematic too